# CTFontGetAscent() differs a lot from ascent of matching font on OSX

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, core-text

Comparing the output of CTFontGetAscent() and the ascent values of the same font on OS X, I get two very different values (taking point size into consideration).

Example:
Helvetica Neue has an ascent of 952 which results in an ascent of 33 for point size 35. CTFontGetAscent returns 16.
Marker Felt (wide) has an ascent of 800 which results in an ascent of 27 pts for point size 35. CTFontGetAscent returns 37.

Taking the value of CTFontGetUnitsPerEm() into consideration does not result in correct values.

Are the on-device fonts really that much different from their "desktop counterparts", or am I missing something? Or is CoreText returning an incorrect result?

Answer (score 2):

(Answering my own question)
Many desktop applications report a different ascent value, found in the font's windows compatability table (the 'OS/2' table).

The raw bytes of the table can be accessed by:
    CTFontCopyTable(myFontRef, 'OS/2', 0);

All bytes in the table are in network order (see http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_ntohs.htm)

The first 2 bytes form the version number. The specification for each table version can be found at http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/os2.htm. Remember to flip the bytes of each field to host order.

The "sTypoAscent" field of the table gives the ascent value. Divide it by the unitsPerEm value provided by CTFont (CTFontGetUnitsPerEm) and you get the percentage ascent of the font.